# Erro ao fazer upload de arquivos codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, file-upload

Estou tendo um problema que não consigo resolver referente a upload de arquivos no php com codeigniter

faço o upload mas me é retornado a mensagem de que não selecionei nenhum arquivo para upload.

View:

```
<form id='formsolicitacao' method='POST' action="ubs/index" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function index(){

        if($this->input->post('submit')){
            $configuracao = array(
                'upload_path'          => './uploads/',
                'allowed_types'        => 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|pdf|jpeg',
                'max_size'             => 0,
                'max_width'            => 0,
                'max_height'           => 0
            );

            $this->load->library('upload');

            $this->upload->initialize($configuracao);


            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                $arquivo = '';


                var_dump($this->input->post('userfile'));
                var_dump(array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()) );


                echo "nao";
            }
            else
            {
                $arquivo =  base_url() . 'uploads/' . $this->upload->data('file_name');

                echo "sim";
            }


            //$dados['resposta'] = $this->modelsolicitacoes->inserir($arquivo);

            echo "submit";
        }


    }
```

Obs.: tirei trechos do código que acho que não é importante para a questão

o retorno que eu obtenho é este:

```
C:\wamp64\www\boldrini\application\controllers\Ubs.php:42:string 'roda6.jpeg' (length=10)
C:\wamp64\www\boldrini\application\controllers\Ubs.php:43:
array (size=1)
  'error' => string '<p>Você não selecionou o arquivo para fazer upload.</p>' (length=57)
naosubmit
```

Ou seja: o var_dump reconhece que existe algo na variável do post, mas o upload não reconhece.

Já tentei colocar a função de upload em um helper, no model, ja tentei alterar as configurações do array `$configuracao`, enfim, não sei o que eu posso fazer para funcionar.

Se alguém puder me dar uma luz, agradeceria muito

Comment: **Dica**: Não remova partes do código que vc não acha relevante. Testei seu código num ambiente MS Windows e não tive problema. O upload ocorre normalmente. Verifique as permissões do `upload_path`.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @ShutUpMagda. Consegui solucionar o problema